# Creating Zspheres in Blender. Trying to add CTRL + A to geometry node modeling

Tags: transforms, sculpting, geometry-nodes, procedural

[image]I have been trying to make a form of Zspheres in blender. I have gotten ico sphers at the vertices, and generated cylinders on the edges. I am having trouble changing the scale of each individual vertices. using "S" hot-key doesn't work, nor does "CTRL+A". Can someone help me out?

{UPDATE} It works!!!Thank you once again to Crantisz for helping me find the missing piece to my puzzle. You sir/mam, are an absolute boss. Anyone who wants to use this setup can go ahead and copy it, I would love to see how people use my little pet project. Tag me on istagram,@sonne3d, so I can check them out.[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vertex groups for that:

[image]

Enter the vertex group in the modifier

[image]

And use it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much man. I have been yanking my hair out over this for a few months now. I tried out your additions to the node tree, and it worked like a charm. If you would like to use the setup, please feel free to add it to your arsenal. And anyone else who wants to use them, go right ahead

Answer (score 0):

[image: joint merging]

The only issue I am having is when the joints are close together they are effecting each other unlike how yours shows, they are warping when moved closer together.
Something in the setup I am missing.

I set the radius input type to float, flipped the field from input to attribute and set vertex group: group

I realize they are sharing the same circle loop to bridge, they need a unique loop per each edge.